# TypeError TypeError: connect() argument 3 must be str, not list

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to python, sqlalchemy and flask. Right now i am trying to do a simple database insert program where artist_name is inserted into a database I have already created.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml
app = Flask(__name__)
db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = ['mysql_db']
mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Fetch form data
        userDetails = request.form
        artist_name = userDetails['artist_name']
        
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO p_artist ( artist_name) VALUES (%s)", (artist_name))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'inserted'
        
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
HTML
 <form method="POST" action="">
    <br>
      artist_name <input type="text" name="artist_name" />
    <br>
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

```
db.yaml

mysql_host: 'localhost'
mysql_user: 'root'
mysql_password: 
mysql_db:**
```

this is the type error

```
TypeError
TypeError: connect() argument 3 must be str, not list
Traceback (most recent call last)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
                try:
                    ctx.push()
                    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
                except Exception as e:
                    error = e
                    response = self.handle_exception(e)
                except:  # noqa: B001
                    error = sys.exc_info()[1]
                    raise
                return response(environ, start_response)
            finally:
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\hope.py", line 25, in index
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 94, in connection
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 81, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\luvch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    TypeError: connect() argument 3 must be str, not list
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.
You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:
    dump() show*emphasized text*s all variables in the frame
    dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated

Comment: `app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ['mysql_password']` and the next line should use `db['mysql_password']`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo, you're loading your database config details as `db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml')` but not referring to that in the `app.config`:

```
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = ['mysql_db']
```

It should be:

```
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']
```